# Trigger que insere valor automático em um registro

Tags: oracle, trigger, sql-insert

Boa tarde, galera. tudo bem com vocês?
Estou tentando criar uma trigger que ao realizar um cadastro de parceiro ele marque automaticamente que o parceiro é cliente. No banco, esse campo é chamado de CLIENTE e recebe o valor 'S', porém, estou me deparando com o seguinte erro ao tentar cadastrar um parceiro :ORA-04098: gatilho 'TESTE.AD_TRG_INC_UPD_TGFPAR' é inválido e a revalidação falhou. Poderiam me ajudar?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AD_TRG_INC_UPD_TGFPAR
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF CLIENTE ON TGFPAR
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF :NEW.CLIENTE ='N' OR :NEW.CLIENTE IS NULL THEN 
       :NEW.CLIENTE := 'S';
END´´´
```

Comment: Neste caso não basta a cláusula DEFAULT?

Comment: Como assim cláusula DEFAULT?

Comment: https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/default-values-for-table-columns-enhancements-12cr1#nulls alter table TGFPAR modify cliente default 'S';

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde,
Agradeço a ajuda. Consegui resolver graças aos conselhos de vocês. A query ficou assim.

```
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON TGFPAR
--REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION; -- corrige mutante trigger
V_CLIENTE VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
SELECT user INTO V_CLIENTE
FROM DUAL;

:new.cliente:= 'S';
END;´´´
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você esteja fazendo confusão entre **UPDATE** e **INSERT**, no caso o campo já existe você quer altera-lo para 'S', no caso você tem que utilizar o **UPDATE**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AD_TRG_INC_UPD_TGFPAR
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF CLIENTE ON TGFPAR
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF :NEW.CLIENTE IS NULL THEN 
       :NEW.CLIENTE := 'S';
END
```

Outro erro que pode está dando é que sempre que você utilizar o **:NEW** ou **:OLD** o próximo valor depois do . (ponto) é o nome da coluna, verifique se realmente é o nome da coluna do valor que você deseja alterar.

Comment: Opa, muito obrigado amigo. Então, realmente o nome da coluna é CLIENTE. Ela vem com status em branco, mas para alguns procedimentos elas precisa ser marcada e o pessoa vem esquecendo. E como todo parceiro recebe esse campo marcado por se tratar de um comprador ou fornecedor, quero por para que ao cadastrar um parceiro ele já venha marcado. Estou começando a mexer com triggers agora e estou levando um couro rs

Comment: ocorreu o mesmo erro ao tentar da forma que me mostrou. Será que tem algo interferindo para criar essa trigger?

Comment: Fiz uma alteração do código o nome da tabela é TGFPAR e o nome da coluna CLIENTE? Se for isso pode testar, provavelmente irá funcionar.

Comment: Eu já tinha feito essa alteração e continuou o mesmo erro. Será que é por que o parceiro está sendo inserido e  ele estaria dando insert e update no mesmo registro?

Comment: Eu notei que você utilizou o BEFORE que é antes, acredito que tenha que usar o AFTER, pode ser que o campo não exista ainda então não tem como fazer o UPDATE em um campo que não existe, alterei o código novamente, faz um teste

Comment: Deu o mesmo erro. Na verdade o campo existe. Caso não seja marcado esse campo ele recebe null, o problema é que esta ocorrendo um erro no cadastro de parceiro onde os funcionários esquecem de marcar que o cara é cliente, ai gera um erro na hora de realizar um pedido de venda. Ao confirmar o cadastro do parceiro, esse campo deve ser auto preenchido. é um campo varchar2 e recebe valor 's'

Comment: Continua o mesmo erro?

Comment: Continua o mesmo erro.

Comment: Como você está criando a trigger? posta o código completo para eu dar uma olhada

Comment: Editei o post com a ultima query que rodei no banco.

Comment: Onde está o create trigger?

Comment: Editei novamente o codigo . Na hora de salvar não pegou  essa parte ai não, só a linha de baixo.

Comment: Alterei novamente, coloquei as referencias

Comment: Deu o mesmo, erro. To achando que é falha do sistema já

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AD_TRG_INC_UPD_TGFPAR
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF CLIENTE ON TGFPAR
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF TRIM(:NEW.CLIENTE) IS NULL THEN 
      :NEW.CLIENTE := 'S';
    END IF;
END;
```

---

Poderia também criar um DEFAULT na coluna

```
 ALTER TABLE TGFPAR
    MODIFY CLIENTE NOT NULL DEFAULT 'S';
```

Aplicando isto garantir não existir valores null

```
UPDATE TGFPAR SET CLIENTE = 'S'
WHERE TRIM(CLIENTE) IS NULL;
```

Comment: O Modify client que passou até irá ajudar os que já foram cadastrados, mas preciso que esse campo seja auto preenchido ao cadastrar novos parceiros. Já a trigger é uma boa. Vou testar aqui, irmão. Valeu por tirar um tempo pra ajudar

Comment: Apareceu o seguinte erro: SQL Error [4084] [42000]: ORA-04084: não pode alterar valores NEW para este tipo de gatilho

Comment: A trigger tem de ser de before.... Coisas de notepad ...

Comment: Entendi. Mas ela é Before e ainda sim deu esse erro.

Comment: Republica a trigger.

Comment: Opa, perdão pela demora,amigo. Estava meio tenso as coisas no serviço. Irei republicar sim.

Comment: Editei a Trigger na postagem, postei a ultima tentativa rs

Comment: Não ficou outra trigger "perdida" de after setando new ? agora não faz sentido ...

Comment: Então, eu meio que to tentando todas as formas possíveis, por que não consigo fazer isso dar certo rs